# In Vue.js, how do I get an input to display something different to the model?

Tags: vue.js

With reference to the following:

https://plnkr.co/edit/1mMThIpE1poiGMh98npf?p=preview

there is a simple example where the input always displays `firstName`.

Suppose I want the input to always display `firstName`, except I want the input to display `Hello John` when the name is `John`, is there a way to do this?

In other words

```
James = James
Mike = Mike
Jill = Jill
John = Hello John
```

Comment: Use a computed property. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `v-model` you will have to use computed `value` property:

```
<input :value="computedName">


computed: {
    computedName: function () {
      return this.firstName == 'John' ? 'Hello ' + this.firstName : this.firstName
    }
  }
```